# How to click on dynamic xpath with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I need to click with puppeteer on a dynamic xpath but I can't achieve to match the path.

This is the dynamic path I need to click

```
 //[@id="Pfb41b20eb4b64727b5db3b2abea2187d_1_oReportCell"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/a
```

The dynamic part starts after the P and ends on the first _

And this is what I have tried so far

```
const download = await page.$x('//id[contains("1_oReportCell")]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/a');

const download = await page.$x('//*[@id^="P"][@id$="_oReportCell"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/a
');
```

Can someone help me out, please.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0, the *ends-with()* function can be expressed as:

```
substring($string, string-length($string) - string-length($pattern) + 1) = $pattern
```

In your XPath expression:

```
//[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 12) = "1_oReportCell"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div/a
```

**Edit**: XPath 2.0+ has a proper [ends-with()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) function, of course.